# Tesseract Miss Identifying "

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an interesting problem, I am trying to get tesseract to extract a set of numbers that represent an imperial dimension, however it continuously identifies the quotation mark ticks as the number 7.

Here is an exact couple of sample images:

[image][image]

Both of these show up as 107 and 167 for example.

Here is my tesseract line (in python): `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(clip, config='--psm 6 -l eng ')`

**EDIT:**
I am using Tesseract 4.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.10. I have also installed and am using the "high accuracy" pre-trained model from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best

Comment: Can't reproduce, I get `10”` and `16”` for Tesseract version 5.0.0.0-alpha. Please provide a [mre], and your `pytesseract` version.

Comment: @HansHirse, thank you for taking a look, I have added an edit with version and further information. Thank you for your help.